# Достать дату и время из строки с определённым префиксом

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

есть код страницы в ней есть строчка `You have access until: 2011-11-27 18:28:45`
мне нужно достать дату и время. используя `preg_match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, и в чем сложности ?

берем данную строку,

```
You have access until: 2011-11-27 18:28:45
```

You have access until: - эта часть строки скорее всего меняться не будет, так что скорее всего хватит обычного

```
echo substr("You have access until: 2011-11-27 18:28:45", strlen("You have access until: "));
```

но если вам уж так хочется применить preg_match - то:

нам нужно сделать маску для даты и времени в заданном формате.

Итак:
\d - цифра
{x} - количество символов которые подходят под маску заданую предыдущими символами. Например: \d{4} - это маска задаёт 4 любых числа.

итого у нас выходит чтото типа:

```
if (preg_match("~You have access until: (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})~", "You have access until: 2011-11-27 18:28:45", $m)) {
    print_r($m);
}
```

Но на самом деле нам бы хватило \d+ в даном случае.